# Trying not to repeat myself in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I find myself repeating a lot of code when writing TypeScript. I am trying to see if I am missing something here.

Typescript touts itself for being able to infer typing. However, this feature seems to break down almost immediately in practice.

So suppose we have something like:

```
const options = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

And then we have some function that will use `options` like that:

```
someFn(options)
```

So the function will look something like:

```
const someFn = (options: { foo: string }) => {
    console.log(options.foo)
}
```

This is fine except when suppose `options` is a larger object. I understand that the way is to set up an interface:

```
interface optionsType {
    foo: 'bar'
    foo1: 'bar1'
    foo2: 'bar2'
    // and many more
}

const options: optionsType = {
    foo: 'bar',
    foo1: 'bar1',
    foo2: 'bar2',
    // and many more
}

const someFn2 = (
    options: optionsType
) => {
    console.log(options.foo)
}

const someFn2 = (
    options: optionsType
) => {
    console.log(options.foo)
}
```

But that is repeating myself. Besides, `options` is already typed by inference (which TypeScript proudly sells). It wouldn't need to be defined, except in this case it has to be in order to re-use typing in the functions.

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *take* the type from `options`.

```
const options = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

type OptionType = typeof options
```

which is the same as writing

```
type OptionType = {
    foo: string;
}
```

You can then refer to this type to the rest of the code.

Additional note: if you do need `foo: 'bar'` instead of `foo: string` in the type as well, you can append `as const` to options.

```
const options = {
    foo: 'bar'
} as const

type OptionType = typeof options
```

which is the same as writing

```
type OptionType = {
    readonly foo: "bar";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in a similar situation where creating new objects was quite boring.

One way to deal with this could be to create a new class, that you may export globally like this

```
// core.models.ts
export class OptionsType = {
  foo: string
  foo1: string
  foo2: string

  constructor(options: OptionsType) {
    this.foo = options.foo || 'bar' // Default value you want
    this.foo1 = options.foo1 || 'bar1'
    this.foo2 = options.foo2 || 'bar2'
  }
}
```

Then, you would be able to call this object as a type, or as a new value

```js
const someFn = (options: OptionsType) => {
    console.log(options.foo)
}

// Or create a new object with default values
const someFn = (options = new OptionsType({})) => {
    console.log(options.foo)
}

// Then you could call it like that
this.someFn({foo: 'bar0'}) // log -> 'bar0'
```

Comment: you still kind of repeat `fooX: string` once everytime don't it?

Comment: @Calvintwr For the class generation yes. Maybe I miss understand your question. Should I remove my answer ?

Comment: it's okay, I think there is value in it as well. I actually upvoted it, but I just wanted to clarify before I accept the other answer.